# Downloaded json file has extra slashes

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I have found a way to download my json file that contains some json content in wordpress, on form submit, by calling on an external file `download.php` that will then execute `header()`. This works, however the json file that I get by downloading has escaped all characters. Even double quotes. And the json I echo out before downloading, doesn't.

Downloaded `.json`:

```
{\"post\":[{\"ID\":3467,\"post_author\":
```

Echoed out `.json`:

```
{"post":[{"ID":3467,"post_author":"1"
```

I've added the menu page:

```
add_menu_page( 'Download JSON', 'Download JSON', 'manage_options', 'custompage', 'download_json', 'dashicons-download', 6000 );
```

In my `download_json()` function, I have

```
$json_out = json_encode($output);

$download = htmlspecialchars($json_out);

echo '<form method="post" action="'.plugins_url().'/my_plugin/download.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="json" value="'.$download.'">
        <button type="submit" class="button-secondary">Download JSON</button>
    </form>';
```

`$output` is my array with stuff in it. The json in the hidden input field looks like the echoed out one. In my `download.php` file I have

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="content.json"');
$json_contents = $_POST['json'];

echo $json_contents;
```

This downloads the `content.json` file when I click on the button, but I have extra escaped characters, and I'm not sure why.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you are using an older PHP? If so, check your phpinfo() if you are using addslashes. If so, that is the reason.

Comment: Couldn't find if I'm using addslashes in my phpinfo, but when I added `stripslashes` as one answer suggested (he deleted it :S), the json looks ok. So I guess that it's enabled. Can I check if it's enabled or not so to use `stripslashes` or not use it?

Comment: I'll post some old code I used for that as an answer (it doesn't fit here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my old function I used on PHP4 to remove slashes, but only if they were automatically added.

Please note that usage of magic_quotes is highly discouraged. (I don't think it even exists in PHP5, not sure)

This function can take an plain value, or an array, and will do it on all elements then. I haven't used it in years, so be sure to test if it does what you want.

```
function stripslashesIfAutoAdded($something){
    // This function removes added slashes
    // It only removes them if they were added.
    $mq_on = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
    if (is_array($something)){
        // loop over it and remove slashes where needed
        $retArr = array();
        foreach($something as $oneElement) {
            if ($mq_on){
                $retArr[] = stripslashes($oneElement);
            } else {
                $retArr[] = $oneElement;
            }
        }
        return $retArr;
    } else {
        if ($mq_on){
            return stripslashes($something);
        } else {
            return $something;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution to check for slashes thanks for the help.